# Acumatica PXSelector cannot get Current another field value in where clause

Tags: acumatica

I have DAC with 2 field below

```
[PXDBInt]
[PXDefault]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Site ID")]
[PXSelector(typeof(Search<DMSViewINSite.siteID>),
    new Type[]
    {
        typeof(DMSViewINSite.siteCD),
        typeof(DMSViewINSite.descr)
    },
    DescriptionField = typeof(DMSViewINSite.descr),
    SubstituteKey = typeof(DMSViewINSite.siteCD))]

public virtual int? SiteID { get; set; }

[PXDBInt]
[PXDefault]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Location ID")]
[PXSelector(typeof(Search<DMSViewINLocation.locationID, Where<DMSViewINLocation.siteID, Equal<Current<siteID>>>>),
    new Type[]
    {
        typeof(DMSViewINLocation.locationCD),
        typeof(DMSViewINLocation.descr)
    },
    DescriptionField = typeof(DMSViewINLocation.descr),
    SubstituteKey = typeof(DMSViewINLocation.locationCD))]
public virtual int? LocationID
```

And I have a FormTab with tab item below

```
<px:PXTabItem Text="Vansales Location">
                <Template>
                    <px:PXGrid ID="PXGrid2" runat="server" TabIndex="-15736" Width="100%" DataSourceID="ds" SkinID="DetailsInTab" KeepPosition="True" SyncPosition="True" StatusField="Availability">
                        <Levels>
                            <px:PXGridLevel DataMember="VansalesLocation">
                                <RowTemplate>
                                    <px:PXSelector ID="edSiteID" runat="server" AutoRefresh="True" DataField="SiteID">
                                    </px:PXSelector>
                                    <px:PXSelector ID="edLocationID" runat="server" AutoRefresh="True" DataField="LocationID">
                                    </px:PXSelector>
                                </RowTemplate>
                                <Columns>
                                    <px:PXGridColumn DataField="SiteID" Width="120px" CommitChanges="True">
                                    </px:PXGridColumn>
                                    <px:PXGridColumn DataField="LocationID" Width="120px">
                                    </px:PXGridColumn>
                                </Columns>
                            </px:PXGridLevel>
                        </Levels>
                        <AutoSize Enabled="True" />
                    </px:PXGrid>
                </Template>
            </px:PXTabItem>
```

I want when I select Site, Location will be load by SiteID, but currently not working. I'm sure 2 view is load correctly data.

Please help me. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found cause of the error above, I missing PXDefault(typeof(Header)) on foreign key.

Thanks for your view.